# How do I implement navigation between android library modules focusing reusability and separation of concerns?

Tags: android, module, navigation

I'm trying to implement a separate navigation module to navigate between android library modules focusing scalability, reusability and module independence. My application architecture is similar to this example:

[image]

**My current approach**

1- Define `NavigatorInterface` for each library

2- Implement each `NavigatorInterface` in `NavigationModule`. (ofcourse navigation module will know about all other library modules but it does not matter as it won't be reused)

Following is the example code for my above mentioned architecture:

**:auth**

|-- LoginActivity

|-- SignupActivity

|-- AuthNavigator

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigatorCoordinator navigator; // how do I achieve this injection, without using Dagger etc.

    .....
    private void signup(){
        navigator.NavigateToSignup(this);
    }

    private void profile(){
        navigator.NavigateToProfile(this);
    }
    .....
}


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigatorCoordinator navigator; // how do I achieve this injection, without using Dagger etc.

    .....
    private void login(){
        navigator.NavigateToLogin(this);
    }

    private void profile(){
        navigator.NavigateToProfile(this);
    }
    .....
}



public interface AuthNavigator {
    void NavigateToLogin(Context context);
    void NavigateToRegister(Context context);
}
```

**:profile**

|-- ProfileActivity

|-- ProfileNavigator

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigatorCoordinator navigator; // how do I achieve this injection, without using Dagger etc.

    .....
    private void about(){
        navigator.NavigateToAbout(this);
    }
    .....
}


public interface ProfileNavigator {
    void NavigateToProfile(Context context);
}
```

**:about**

|-- AboutActivity

|-- AboutNavigator

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigatorCoordinator navigator; // how do I achieve this injection, without using Dagger etc.

    .....
    private void profile(){
        navigator.NavigateToProfile(this);
    }
    .....
}


public interface AboutNavigator {
    void NavigateToAbout(Context context);
}
```

The above approach is a try to eliminate circular dependency within same module `:auth` as well as between two modules `:profile` & `:about`. Below is the implementation of `:navigation`.

**:navigation**

|-- Navigator

```
public class Navigator implements AuthNavigator, ProfileNavigator, AboutNavigator {
    @Override
    public void NavigateToLogin(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void NavigateToSingup(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SignupActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void NavigateToProfile(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void NavigateToAbout(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AboutActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1- I believe, I need to implement the `NavigatorCoordinator` in `:navigation` module, but how do I do it? Any example for this implementation?

2- How do I inject the dependency of `NavigatorCoordinator` in each Activity Class residing in different `modules` without using Deggar or any other framework? Can we do it by using `Application` class, if yes please give an example of implementation?

3- How do I setup the `Launcher` activity from any library, for example: `LoginActivity`?

4- How do I call the `:navigation` module from `:app` module in a way that it starts a specific activity, for example: `ProfileActivity`?

5- Is this a good inter-module navigation approach to achieve reusability, scalability and separation of concerns?

6- Are there any other similar and good approaches? Any code examples? Link to article?

**PS:** Please don't tell me to use Navigation Architecture Component.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can apply some object oriented workaround for this. First of all, you can consider declaring an navigator interface inside common module. Since every module is independent and doesn't know each other, you need to follow a more generic approach. You can define something like a Navigator interface

```
interface Navigator {
    fun navigate(activity: Activity, bundle: Bundle)
}
```

Now consider opening activities without referencing it, but with a key. You should have a factory to map your given key to an activity navigator. You can think like you want to open AboutActivity with a key, since you don't have its reference. The key can be an integer or maybe class package name, it doesn't matter. I'll stick with package name as a key.

```
interface NavigatorFactory {
    fun of(packageName: String): Navigator
}
```

And somehow you need to get those navigators when navigating inside an activity. An ideal way is to use application class, because you have its reference in any of your activities. So we defined an interface to apply to application class.

```
interface NavigatorApplication {
    fun getNavigatorFactory(): NavigatorFactory
}
```

So we end our implementations in common module. Let's continue with app module.
You need to start declaring implementations of these interfaces

```
class AboutActivityNavigator: Navigator {
    public void navigate(Activity activity, bundle: Bundle) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, AboutActivity::class.java)
        activity.startActivity(intent, bundle)
    }
}
```

Factory implementation to return these Navigator instances.

```
object NavigatorFactoryImpl: NavigatorFactory {
    fun get(key: String): Navigator {
        when(key) {
            is "com.example.AboutActivity" -> AboutActivityNavigator()
        }
    }
}
```

Provide factory with an interface that known by modules. This way modules can reach interface and receive factory instance.

```
class Application: NavigatorApplication {
    val factoryImpl = NavigatorFactoryImpl()
    fun getNavigatorFactory() = factoryImpl
}
```

We are done with app module too. Now you can navigate to every activity you want inside any of your modules.

```
class ProfileActivity: Activity() {
    fun navigateToAboutActivity() {
        (application as? NavigatorApplication)?
            .getNavigatorFactory()
            .of("com.example.AboutActivity")
            .navigate(this, Bundle())
    }
}
```

In the end everything comes with a price. Your modules are totally independent. But don't forget, you are still passing some hardcoded key to open an activity. And besides, you have no guarantees for type safety. If you pass something key-value like ("page-id",34) inside a bundle, you may never know if target activity accepts same key and same type.

And if you have a single-activity based architecture in the future, you can also check [Jetpack Navigation by Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide `:about` into two different sub-modules, one is `:implementation` and another is `:navigate`. Put `navigationInterface` in the `:navigate` module and import `:navigate` sub-modules in the `:navigation` module this way you won't face the problem of circular dependency. Also, import the `:navigation` module into the `:implementation` module.